# Clicking noise from fridge, and won't hold temp anymore

Tags: refrigerator

I have a ~10 y/o (predates my purchase of the house) built-in Sub Zero 700TC. A day or two ago it started clicking every few minutes and showed codes 24 and 50, both of which reference the compressor running too much. I cleaned the coil with no effect, and the clicking noise is atypical and loud - I had never heard it before and I generally notice things like this.

Visually, it's coming from what I think is the start capacitor(?):

[image]

Or is that a relay too? I don't understand why a capacitor would make noise (they generally don't).

Either way, before I call a tech I want to see if I can fix it myself. Can this be a source of the clicking / issue? Also - the refrigerant line was still hot to the touch, so I feel like it's working at least somewhat?

Any ideas?

Comment: Get a replacement start relay asap and install it. This is almost certainly the cause. Exercise caution around that capacitor; they hold quite a bit of juice even after unplugging. Story time: I had the same problem and our fridge failed before I replaced it; getting a start relay used cost me 25$. Replacing the contents of the fridge was around 120$ :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our refrigerator suffered a similar problem a few months ago. The tech arrived and replaced what he called a starting relay. I had also suspected a capacitor problem, but the relay apparently precedes the circuit with the capacitor. Your description of clicking is consistent with a relay problem.

Comment: That is almost certainly the cause (the start relay)